# Weak $L^p$ convergence for passing to the limit in piecewise linear approximation of sign function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Consider
$$ S_\epsilon(\xi) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } \xi > \epsilon \\ 
\xi/\epsilon &\text{ if }  |\xi| < \epsilon \\
-1 &\text{ if }  \xi < - \epsilon 
\end{cases}$$
which is a smoothed version of the $\mathrm{sign}$ function.

Suppose that $u_n \to u$ weakly in $L^p([0,1])$ for all $p \in [1,\infty]$ as $n \to \infty$. Is it true that $S_\epsilon(u_n-1) \to S_\epsilon(u-1)$ weakly in some $L^p$?

Comment: Where does $p$ live and what kind of convergence are you asking about?

Comment: @zhw. we can take all $p \in [1,\infty]$. $S_\epsilon(u_n)$ is a sequence of numbers.

Comment: $S_\varepsilon : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1]$, whereas $u_n \in L^p([0,1])$. How is $u_n - 1$ defined? Is it a function? If it is a function, how is $S_\varepsilon(u_n - 1)$ defined? If it is defined pointwise, $S_\varepsilon(u_n(x) - 1)$ for each $x \in [0,1]$, then $S_\varepsilon(u_n(x))$ is indexed by both $n$ and $x$.

Comment: @snar I see. Yes, we define it pointwise and the covergence that we seek is also weak in $L^p$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: What did you try ? Did you try the definition of weak convergence and then cutting the integral depending on the value of $u_n$ ?

Comment: So then $S_\epsilon(u_n)$ is not a sequence of numbers; it's a sequence of functions.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, that's true.

Comment: I can give you a counterexample if "all $p$" means $p\in[1,\infty)$.  Would that work for you?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Sure, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\epsilon \le 1$.  On $[0,1]$, let
$$ u_n(x) = \cases{ 4 & if $x \in \left[\tfrac{2j}{2n},\tfrac{2j+1}{2n}\right)$\\ 
 0 & if $x \in \left[\tfrac{2j+1}{2n},\tfrac{2j+2}{2n}\right)$.
} $$
Then $u_n \rightharpoonup 2$ in $L^p([0,1])$ for $1 \le p < \infty$, but $S_\epsilon(u_n-1) \rightharpoonup 0 \ne \epsilon = S_\epsilon(2-1)$.

Not sure about $p = \infty$, but I doubt this counterexample  works.